# CSS styles not appearing for particular class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My `css/main.css` file is linked to my `index.html` file correctly and all the CSS code inside works with all my HTML elements.

However, I am trying to get an image which displays information when hovered over which isn't working - the CSS isn't being recognized, I reckon there's some problem with the classes.

```css
.box {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(177, 208, 113, 0.8);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
}

.box:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container margintop-50">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="box">
        <img src="img/secgen.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle">
        <div class="boxContent">
          <h3 class="title">Sivan Chakravarty</h3>
          <span class="post">Secretary General</span>
          <ul class="links">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: It seems to be working perfectly here. I'm using Sublime Text, everything is set right; but this just will not work on my browser. No errors in console, nothing.

Comment: so, can you post your online or fiddle to show the problem such that we can find whats its reason?

Comment: [link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cL361fb0/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I checked [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cL361fb0/1/) and found a very strange issue in it: all space chars in your css are actually not SPACE char but char code **160** which is visually like as space but dosen't recognized by browsers!

Replace all of those in a text editor like notepad++ you will see it works as in code snippet!

Also, you can see updated fiddle [Here.](https://jsfiddle.net/cL361fb0/2/)

```css
.box{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.box:before{
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(177, 208, 113, 0.8);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
}
.box:hover:before{
    opacity: 1;
}

.box .boxContent{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
}
.box .title{
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    top: 18%;
    transform: scale(5);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s;
}
.box .post{
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: italic;
    position: relative;
    top: 18%;
    transform: scale(5);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
}
.box:hover .title,
.box:hover .post{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
}
.box .links{
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 23%;
    transform: scale(5);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s;
}
.box:hover .links{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.box .links li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.box .links li:last-child{
    margin-right: 0;
}
.box .links li a{
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container margintop-50">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="box">
      <img src="img/secgen.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle" style="height:250px">
        <div class="boxContent">
         <h3 class="title">Sivan Chakravarty</h3>
            <span class="post">Secretary General</span>
              <ul class="links">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
              </ul>
         </div>          
        </div>
      </div>                                                                                           
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: did you check my answer? whats your feedback?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the before should be with 2 colons.

```
.box::before{}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

hover working check here .....
    https://jsfiddle.net/cL361fb0/

```
    .box {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(177, 208, 113, 0.8);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out 0s;
}

.box:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: this is not an answer